# Add python version to vscode in Debian9

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debian

In VSCode I can press ctrl+shift+p -> Then I choose select python interpreter: Now I can choose between the installed python versions. They are; python, located att /usr/bin/python and python3 located at /usr/bin/python3.

Now I also have another version of python installed on my Debian9 machine. I can run this by typeing /usr/local/python/bin/python in the terminal.

I would like to run this version of python as the debugger. But I am unable to choose this version in VSCode. I beleive that all I have to do is to add a path in some config file or a PATH variable but I've not been able to locate something that will make this work.

Any one got any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it was quite simple.

- Hit the combination ctrl+shift+p
- Select "Open Workspace Settings"/"Open User Settings":

This will open 2 windows, the default settings and also another window where you can switch between "workspace settings" and "user settings".

Just add the following to the configfile of your choice:

```
{
    ... //other config
    "python.pythonPath": "your pythonPath"
}
```